# Odd Outer Joining Structure for a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I am importing a view from an old database as part of a software upgrade and I saw this `FROM` clause as I was working.

```
FROM 
    t_store_master AS STM 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.t_shipping AS SHP 
INNER JOIN 
    t_hu_master AS HUM 
INNER JOIN 
    t_stored_item AS STO ON HUM.hu_id = STO.hu_id
      ON SHP.shipment_id = HUM.reserved_for 
      AND SHP.location_id = HUM.location_id 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.t_carrier AS CAR ON SHP.carrier_code = CAR.carrier_code 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.t_order_detail AS ORD 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.t_order AS ORM ON ORD.order_number = ORM.order_number
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.t_pick_detail PDL ON ORD.order_number = PDL.order_number
       ON STO.type = PDL.pick_id
       ON STM.store_id = HUM.control_number_2
```

It is my understanding that `OUTER JOIN` requires an `ON` clause in order to be interpreted properly by the compiler. However, there must be some edge case scenarios I am unaware of because the code above returns good data without throwing any errors.

After some goggling and reading up on MSDN standards for `OUTER JOIN`s, I am still at a loss for what the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` are doing in this query.

I do know that the multiple `ON` clauses beneath the `INNER JOIN`s are necessary. There seems to be some kind of hidden or implied mapping being done between the `ON` clauses and the `OUTER JOIN`s. Past that I cannot tell what the purpose of writing a query this way would be.

Could someone shed some insight on how this works and why it would be written this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is allowed.  It makes slightly more sense with parentheses:

```
FROM t_store_master STM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     (dbo.t_shipping SHP INNER JOIN
      (t_hu_master HUM INNER JOIN
       t_stored_item STO 
       ON HUM.hu_id = STO.hu_id
      )
      ON SHP.shipment_id = HUM.reserved_for AND
         SHP.location_id = HUM.location_id 
     ) INNER JOIN
     (dbo.t_carrier CAR 
      ON SHP.carrier_code = CAR.carrier_code LEFT OUTER JOIN
      ((dbo.t_order_detail ORD INNER JOIN
        dbo.t_order ORM 
        ON ORD.order_number = ORM.order_number
       ) INNER JOIN
       dbo.t_pick_detail PDL
       ON ORD.order_number = PDL.order_number
      )
      ON STO.type = PDL.pick_id
     )
     ON STM.store_id = HUM.control_number_2
```

That said, I would recommend *never* writing a query like this and rewriting the query ASAP if it is in production code.  At the very least, add the parentheses!

Parentheses are almost never needed in the `FROM` clause to express `JOIN`s (there is one case where I do happen to use them).  Non-interleaved `ON` clauses are never needed -- or at least, I have never had occasion to use them or think they were the best way to write a query.  But, both are allowed.

Comment: This Query `SELECT *
FROM TEST
 LEFT JOIN TEST as TEST2
 LEFT JOIN TEST as TEST3 ON TEST2.i=TEST3.i ON TEST3.i = TEST.i
WHERE TEST.i<=3` works, so above makes sence…

Comment: Thanks Gordon. My coworker who came across this problem asked me what I thought about it. I told him I've never seen something like that before, but I can ask @Gordon Linoff. Didn't expect you to be on for another couple hours though. I'll test the parentheses and then accept the answer. Could you hazard a guess as to why someone would write a query this way?

Comment: @Edward . . . My first guess is intentional obfuscation.  Few SQL users realize that `ON` clauses do not need to be interleaved.  Perhaps the code was converted from old-style `join`s with the `where` clauses turned into `on` clauses in the order they appeared.  If you notice, you have to rearrange the `on` clauses to interleave the `ON`s.

Comment: For completeness, I want to say that this entire `FROM` clause was scrapped. We went ahead and re-wrote this join using much simpler `INNER JOIN` formatting. I would add that several experienced developers took a stab at piecing together what this query was doing and failed. Even Gordon's final answer write-up contains an error. He still gave the correct answer though which is to never use this in a PROD environment.